# How do I automatically update new data in ListView React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am working on a mobile app for a news portal where I will have different urls (endpoints) which will contain same type of json data depending upon different  news topics. I want to use one list view to show all these data when clicked on respective news topic. For example, if I click news topic **Apple**, list view will show news on that topic **Apple** and of i click **Banana**, list view should be updated with new data from **Banana** topic.

So far, I have tried, on topic clicked, set the state value 'url' to certain url. But I am not getting result as expected.

Can anyone guide me through the process, please ? Please do not ignore because this post doesn't contain codes. I need ideas on how to do so.

Noob here, Thanks.

Comment: search something about SyncAdapters they help to update data themselves by automatic requests

Comment: 1-you should be get data from endpoints after that you should update to your dataSource onClick events.                              2- create function and send request which is you needed afrer that updare your datasource on state.

Answer (score 0):

Here some code to get your project started, you have to modify links and how to handle response. Hope it helps:

```
export default class News extends Component{

 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.dsinit = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1,r2) => r1 != r2 });
  var items = this.dsinit.cloneWithRows([]);
  this.state = {
    url:'http://www.google.com',
    items:items,
  };
 }


 renderRow(row){
  return <Text>row</Text>
 }

 async fetchNews(){
  let response = await fetch(this.state.url,{
    method:'POST',
    body: {data:1}
  });
  let responseJson = await response.json();
  this.setState({items:this.dsinit.cloneWithRows(responseJson)});

 }

 changeTopic(){
  this.setState({url:'anotherurl.com'});
  this.fetchNews();
 }

 render(){
  return (
   <View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.changeTopic() />
    <ListView dataSource={this.state.items} renderRow={(row) => this.renderRow(row)} />
   </View>
  );
 }

}
```